# How calculate mean of last 14 days using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to be able to calculate the growth rates of Covid-19 cases per cities here in the Philippines. I'm using the department of health public cases dataset which contains caseID, date when case was confirmed, what city the case is, among many.

I tried using the groupby method to split the data into cities and dates, count the cases per day, calculate cumulative sum of these counts, the daily percentage change and finally the mean of percent change in the past 14 days.

I am able to do these but what I can't figure out is how to combine them again to a dataset containing Cities and their average growth rate in past 14 days.

Here's what I had so far:

```
import pandas as pd

cases_df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/doh_datadrops/DOH%20Data%20Drop%2020200518.csv',
                      parse_dates=[5,6,7,9,17])

#cast data to appropriate types for easy handling
for col in ['AgeGroup', 'Sex','RemovalType', 'Admitted', 'RegionRes','ProvRes','CityMunRes',
            'CityMuniPSGC','HealthStatus','Quarantined','Pregnanttab']:
    cases_df[col] = cases_df[col].astype('category')
for col in ['DateRepConf', 'DateDied', 'DateRecover', 'DateRepRem','DateOnset']:
    cases_df[col] = cases_df[col].astype('datetime64')
cases_df.Age = cases_df.Age.astype('Int64')

list_cases_by_city_by_date = cases_df.groupby(['CityMunRes','DateRepConf'])['CaseCode'].count().cumsum().pct_change()
```

The last groupby produces a multi-index list:

```
CityMunRes  DateRepConf
ABUCAY      2020-01-30     NaN
            2020-02-03     NaN
            2020-02-05     NaN
            2020-03-06     NaN
            2020-03-07     NaN
                          ... 
ZARRAGA     2020-05-14     0.0
            2020-05-15     0.0
            2020-05-16     0.0
            2020-05-17     0.0
            2020-05-18     0.0
Name: CaseCode, Length: 28336, dtype: float64
```

Now I can use the following code the calculate growth rate from last 14 days if I specify the city:

```
list_cases_by_city_by_date.loc['ABUCAY'].tail(14).mean()
0.03571428571428571
```

But I wanted was to have a simple dataframe with 'CityMunRes' and 'Ave_Growth' as columns, something that looks like this:

```
|   | City   | Ave_Growth |
|---|--------|------------|
| 0 | ABUCAY | 0.03       |
| 1 | Bxxxx  | 0.02       |
| 2 | Cxxxx  | 0.50       |
|   | ...    |            |
| n | Zxxx   | 0.2        |
```

But I'm hitting a beginner's wall. I'm sure the solution is so simple. :)

Help pls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Bettter solution:

```
list_cases_by_city_by_date.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tail(14).mean())
```

How about this? You make a dictionary of each one, using your bit of code, and then throw them all into a dataframe.

```
d = {city: list_cases_by_city_by_date.loc[city].tail(14).mean() 
     for city in list_cases_by_city_by_date.index.get_level_values('CityMunRes')}

pd.DataFrame(data=d.values(), index=d.keys(), columns=['mean'])
```

Edit: Btw, when I try to run the code you supplied, I get `0.75`, not `0.03571428571428571` when i run

```
list_cases_by_city_by_date.loc['ABUCAY'].tail(14).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks @Bertil. It works. (and btw your code produced the same mean 0.0357). I was wondering if there's a way to chain a agg method in groupby to do the same thing.

Comment: Hm, strange. Not sure. By the way, if this answered your question please click the gray checkmark on the left side of this answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi @bertil thank you for the advice and the help. I am still looking for a way to do it through grouby agg method. Is it ok for you if I leave this open for now? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer @gio888